# Explorer "держит" файл

Tags: файлы, internet-explorer

Кратко о проблеме:

1. открываем Explorer
2. Открываем страницу, в которой есть загрузка файлов
3. Выбираем файл
4. Загружаем с помощью Ajax
5. Explorer держит файл пока не будет закрыт.

Какую проблему это порождает?
Тут входит конфликт интересов доступа к файлу между ACAD(например) и Explorer

порядок действий, который приводит к потере файла:

1. Открываем DWG файл в ACAD
2. Загружаем этот же файл, как описано выше
3. Закрываем ACAD
4. При выводе запроса на сохранение жмём "да"

   4.1 далее магия ACAD, он создает файл Save????.bak и сохраняет данные туда

   4.2 удаляет исходный файл

   4.3 переименовывает Save????.bak в имя исходного файла

естественно п.4.2 не выполнится, т.к. файл занят Explorer, и п.4.3 соответственно. А на винду ставиться триггер, как только файл отцепит приложение - грохнуть его

5. Да и хрен ты с ним закрываем ACAD
6. Закрываем Explorer
7. Файл чудесным образом пропал, т.к. отработал триггер винды.

Теперь собственно решение:

Заставить EXplorer отвязываться от файла, когда загрузка не происходит. Как это сделать?

UPD: Аналогичная проблема на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/76664/)

Comment: То есть, Вы спрашиваете как пофиксить бажный iexplorer?

Comment: @KoVadim я спрашиваю есть ли способ сказать IExplorer так не делать. Может это способ защиты у него такой от инопланетян, а решается это где-то в недрах настроек.

Comment: я думаю, что это у него просто такая особенность. И единственный способ это "пофиксить" - снести его.

вполне возможно, что если у Вас какой то специальный случай, то можно написать свой сервис, который будет следить за нужными файлами и восстанавливать их.